# How AnimatedSprite smoothly move on line with on touch and constant speed in andengine?

Tags: andengine

I am developing demo game application in my game application i want to move my animatedSprite on perfect line that is drawn by user with exactly on touch . And my sprite have to move its constant speed whether user draw line fast or slow.

currently i have used pathmodifier but in this case after user draw path for sprite then and then only possible to move my sprite because pathmodifier takes path and in path we have to give all points statically (predefined) and its length . like below

```
      final Path path = new Path(xListLength);
      PathModifier pathModifier = new PathModifier(velocity, path);
```

but i want my sprite move exactly when user touch on it and when user draw path for it my sprite follow its path having its constant speed. how can i do this in andengine .?

Comment: have you found your answer. if yes please post to help others..

Comment: @DeepakSwami :still now i couldn't find the answer of above question.